# Triggering Cloud Function on update to object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a test Cloud Function (CF) to trigger on update to an object in Cloud Storage.

```
exports.test_cf = (event, callback) => {
    console.log("Test CF executed successfully");
    callback();
}
```

Deployed above function using:

```
gcloud functions deploy --runtime nodejs6 --trigger-resource [BUCKET-NAME] --trigger-event google.storage.object.archive --timeout=540s --verbosity=info
```

After setting the versioning on the bucket, I copy a file to the bucket using `gsutil` as follows:

```
gsutil cp <file> gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/
```

Above command triggered CF. Why is that? As per GCP documentation, `google.storage.archive` triggers CF only on updates.

Another question: How to update objects in buckets using `gsutil`? I see `gsutil rewrite` but it is not same as update.

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post, otherwise it may get closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 2):

> Above command triggered CF. Why is that?

You enabled bucket versioning and then used the `gsutil` command to copy a file in the bucket. This made a live copy of the file available in the bucket and created an archived version of it, for more information you can visit the [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) documentation. You can verify that by running the `gsutil ls -a gs://[BUCKET_NAME]` command, for more information you can visit the [Using Object Versioning > Listing archived object versions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#list) documentation. So using the `-trigger-event google.storage.object.archive` as you used, it will trigger the Cloud Function as it is specified in [Google Cloud Storage Triggers > Object Archive](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_archive) documentation, `"This event is sent when a live version of an object is archived or deleted."`.

> Another question: How to update objects in buckets using gsutil?

If you want to update the object's metadata, you can visit the [Objects: update](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/update) documentation link for more information. However, if you want to update the object it self, you can just upload a new version of the object either from `Google Cloud Console` or using the `gsutil cp ...` command as specified in the [cp - Copy files and objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) documentation. This will archive the old object with new version reference number and will make the new version of the object live in the bucket.